# IE gradient solid in the middle, faded on the left and right

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gradient

I'm trying to make a gradient which would be faded on the left and right, but solid in the middle. Is this possible? I've made my research, but couldn't find any tutorial online.

P.S. This is for Internet Explroer

Comment: Try this - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: I tried that one. It only gives me a two sided gradient - start color and end color

Comment: That's what the color stops are for.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a little vague but it's just a matter of applying color stops as and when required.

If you apply two color stops at different points but the color is the same at both...you get  solid color in the middle.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5hz27nh/3/)

**CSS** (unprefixed)

```
.box {
    width:25%;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid lightgrey;
    display: inline-block;
}

.one {
background: linear-gradient(to right, 
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,
        rgba(0,0,255,1) 25%, /* intermediate color stop */
        rgba(0,0,255,1) 75%, /* second intermediate stop */
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%)
        ; /* W3C */
}
```

Use the [**Gradient Editor**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for this

Comment: I know about stops, it works on most browsers, but what about IE?      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8f8d1b', endColorstr='#8f8d1b', GradientType=1 ) !important;

Comment: Which version of IE are you trying to support? You don't mention and specifics in your question. IF IE9, see the option in the Gradient Editor link.